# update multiple MySQL rows at once

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP Code that selects rows from a database and puts the data in form fields:

```
$global_sql2="SELECT name, field, value FROM global_settings";
$global_rs2=mysql_query($global_sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($global_result2=mysql_fetch_assoc($global_rs2))
{
    echo '<tr>
                <td><strong>'.$global_result2["name"].'</strong></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="'.$global_result2["field"].'" size="50" value="'.$global_result2["value"].'" /></td>
            </tr>';
}
```

then this PHP code on the submit page:

```
$global_sql3="SELECT name, field, value FROM global_settings";
$global_rs3=mysql_query($global_sql3,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($global_result3=mysql_fetch_assoc($global_rs3))
{
    if($_POST[$global_result3["field"]] != $global_result3["value"])
    {
        $sql="UPDATE global_settings set value = '".$_POST[$global_result3["field"]]."' where field = '".$global_result3["field"]."' ";
        $rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
        echo '<h3><font color="#FF0000">'.$global_result3["name"].'</font> Successfully Updated to <font color="#FF0000">'.$_POST[$global_result3["field"]].'</font></h3>';
    }
}
```

i want to be able to update more than just one field - the above works fine for just the value column in the database but i want to be able to do 5 columns

how can i do this?

P.S: Im not worried about SQL Injection as this code is not public

Comment: "I don't care about SQL injection as this code isn't public" is the laziest and worst excuse for making bad practise/insecure code. It really doesn't lengthen develop time enough to worry about.

Comment: are you looking to set different values across multiple fields or just set one value to multiple fields?

Comment: @h2ooooooo thanks for your 'Non Constructive' comment but its not lazy, i just haven't learnt MySQLi or PDO as none of my code is public. Plus i didn't say 'i don't care' i said 'I'm not worried' - thanks

Comment: @Chausser I have a table with 5 columns, i want to be able to display ALL rows in the table and update each column all in one form/query

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for then is setting the columns using the comma delimited field names:

```
UPDATE `tableName` SET `field1` = 'value', `field2` = 'value', `field3` = 'value' WHERE `field` = 'fieldname';
```

If you want to update multiple rows with different values within 1 query you will need to use case statements. A quick google search returned a pretty straight forward tutorial [here](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/)

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET field1 = CASE mainField
        WHEN mainFieldName1 THEN 'value'
        WHEN mainFieldName2 THEN 'value'
        WHEN mainFieldName3 THEN 'value'
    END,
    field2 = CASE mainField
        WHEN mainFieldName1 THEN 'New Title 1'
        WHEN mainFieldName2 THEN 'New Title 2'
        WHEN mainFieldName3 THEN 'New Title 3'
    END
WHERE mainField IN (mainFieldName1,mainFieldName2,mainFieldName3)
```

Comment: i know how to do that, but its how to update multiple rows at once. like in my example

Comment: So you want to show for example a list of "products" and have that be an edit page and then when the form is submitted update all the products with the submitted data?

Comment: thats kind of what my code above does but its only updating the one column based on the name of the text input

Comment: Added a link i found doing a quick google search should do what you are looking to do.

Comment: hmmm  - okay, the amount of rows displayed is going to be dynamic so i can't run the SQL using set field1, set field2 etc

Comment: If you post what you are getting in your $_POST variable i can give you a more accurate query

Comment: That just means that you will need to build that section of the query dynamically, so use a for/foreach loop from your post to build the query then execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't care about SQL injection, you should be learning best practices not to mention PDO has a nicer, cleaner OO syntax. You can use use a single page for this too rather than a separate PHP file.

Mixing SQL, PHP and HTML all together in close proximity isn't easy on the eyes and doesn't maintain well. I've written some small helper functions to promote reusability and readability.

```
<?php

$dbh=false;

//Connect to your DB with PDO, only create the connection once
function getDbConnection() {
    global $dbh;
    $dbh = $dbh ? $dbh : new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=myDb', 'root', '');
    return $dbh;
}

function getSettings(){
    return getDbConnection()->query('SELECT * from global_settings');
}

function updateSettings(){
    foreach($_POST['settings'] as $key => $value){
        //Use a prepared statement with named parameters
        $query = getDbConnection()->prepare('UPDATE global_settings set value=:value WHERE field=:field');
        //Use named params to mitigate security issues
        $query->bindParam(':value', $value);
        $query->bindParam(':field', $key);
        $query->execute();
    }
}

// Has the form been submitted?
if(isset($_POST['settings']))
    updateSettings();

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <?php foreach(getSettings() as $setting): ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label><?= $setting['field'] ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="settings[<?= $setting['field'] ?>]" size="50" value="<?= $setting['value'] ?>" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <input type='submit' />
</form>
```

This is based on the following DB schema:

[image: DB schema]

And you will get a form like this:

[image: Form]

There's a good PDO starter here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/